# Beamer Name of Currently Active Theme

Tags: beamer

Is there a way, in `beamer`, to get the string name of the currently active theme? I want to write a class based on beamer that (1) loads a specific theme if the user didn't specify one and (2) performs certain modifications based on which theme is loaded.

Here is a MWE of what I am looking for:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtEndPreamble{
\makeatletter

\IfStrEqCase*{\beamer@theme}{
  {default}{%
    \usetheme{Berlin}
  }{Madrid}{%
    % do something
  }{metropolis}{%
    % do something else
  }%
}[]

\makeatother
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Hello World
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use hooks to change your variable if certain theme files are loaded:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\beamertheme{default}
\AddToHook{file/beamerthememoloch.sty/after}{\def\beamertheme{moloch}}
\AddToHook{file/beamerthemeMadrid.sty/after}{\def\beamertheme{Madrid}}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Hello World \beamertheme
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(keep in mind that the default theme is always loaded, even if some parts of it are later overwritten by other themes)